# How can you detect wether any music is playing in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

In my game, I want to play music sometimes. But music that is already playing shouldn’t be overridden.

So how can I

1. Check if music is playing
2. Manage that sound

Ideally in an global interface like `this.sound`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML5AudioSound` has `isPlaying` member.

```
// inside scene method, create sound
const music = this.sound.add('music-name', {});
music.play();

// and later
if(music.isPlaying) {

}
```

See
https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/Phaser.Sound.HTML5AudioSound#isPlaying
and
https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/Phaser.Sound.HTML5AudioSoundManager

(`this.sound` is `HTML5AudioSoundManager` instance)

Comment: But can I access all sounds through this API?

Comment: @MoPaMo only way to play sound is adding it by `HTML5AudioSoundManager`. So you will have access to every sound. Also, take in account that `music-name` is not a file name, i'ts resource key loaded by `scene.load.audio(key, url);`